# Background turns grey when opaque

Tags: wpf, xaml, background, opacity

Here's my code:

```
var windows = Application.Current.Windows;
var backgroundWindow = windows[windows.Count - 1];
backgroundWindow.Background = Brushes.White;
backgroundWindow.Opacity = 0.5;

SpecialLettersLayout layout = new SpecialLettersLayout((SmartButton)button, KeyboardViewModel);
layout.Show();
```

When I open a new window, I want the old one (the one in the background to have an opacity of 0.5. When I run the app, here's what I get:

[image]

As you can see, the background is kinda grey. How can I replace the grey color with white?

Comment: Do you want the bottom window to actually be transparent, or are you trying to make it look less contrasty to bring attention to your foreground window?

Comment: Is that foreground window a popup modal? If so you're trying to fight the screen overlay built into its template, you'll want to change that, not the opacity of a window itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Window.Background` is turning grey when you set the `Opacity` to `0.5` because the actual background of the `Window` is `Black`. You can verify this by setting the following:

```
backgroundWindow.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

Instead of setting the `Window.Opacity` to `0.5`, set the `Opacity` of any container control to `0.5` so that you are *not* making the `White Window.Background` opaque, but making the container opaque instead, leaving the `White Window.Background`:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="White" Opacity="0.5" />
        <!-- Your main content -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

What fixed my problem was adding this:

```
AllowsTransparency="True"
```

in my window. @Sheridan was right though, when I set:

```
backgroundWindow.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

I got black background. I don't know why, I never set the background of any of my windows to black.